# Check session in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, session, testing

I am new to CODEIGNITER framework and i have a problem to check whether is set session['username']

in "php" I would just do :

```
if( is set ($_SESSION['username'])){
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];
        //...more code here
    }  else {
        //more code here
    }
```

But i don't know how to test that in this framework.
Thanks to everyone willing to help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this way

```
if($this->session->userdata('username')){
     // do something when exist
}else{
    // do something when doesn't exist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if($this->session->userdata('username')){
    //enter code here
}
```

for setting session

```
$this->session->set_userdata('username','your_username');
```

For more info https://ellislab.com/codeIgniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Codeigniter 3 you can use the magic getters and setters method for session library.

To set a session var:

```
$this->session->username = 'your_username';
```

And to get a session var:

```
echo $this->session->username;
```